# How to iterate the ParseJSON output in power automate to get the item's key values

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, json

I have SharePoint List field having Json value in it. I am parsing that json string through parsejson action with the power automate. Now I want to iterate through the JSON object to verify few key values if exists or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not provided your JSON input and output values for [Parse JSON] action in Power Automate, so not sure about the JSON structure.

Usually, a collection fed into [Parse JSON] will have an array called **[results]**, which is the top level array. It may contain other nested arrays.

See an example of getting users from a SharePoint Group and processing the user collection using [Parse JSON] and [Apply to each] actions.

[image]

**Sample input to [Parse JSON]**

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {        
        "Title": "Hello Lastisa",
        "Email": "SomeEmail@contoso.com"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Schema used for [Parse JSON]**

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "d": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "results": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "Title": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Email": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "required": [
                            "Title",
                            "Email"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use [Apply to each] for processing [results] array

[image]